# Write lambda-bar in matplotlib string

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to know how I can write lambda-bar (similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96479/how-can-i-type-lambda-bar) but within matplotlib plotting string (I have got a probability density that is normalized over the reduced compton volume). Is there a way to add such symbols to matplotlib? According to the wiki it does not support them natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(edgecolor='k',linewidth=1).suptitle('\u019B')
plt.show()
```

more verbose, more explicit

```
lambdabar = '\u019B'
title = f'This title contains a {lambdabar} character.'
```

Comment: Usually every search engine can give useful information when asked "unicode <description of what you need>"